# If $f$ is continuous a.e. on a compact set, does it still attains maximum and minimum?

Tags: real-analysis

> It is well-known that a continuous function $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is such that $f(c)\leq f(x) \leq f(d)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and some $c,d\in [a,b]$. Does that still holds if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continous a.e.?

I was trying to mimic the proof for the continuous everywhere case. The proof that I know first show that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ by contradiction. Later, it will use that to ensure that there is a sequence of points converging to the supremum. So, we assume that $f$ is continuous a.e. and not bounded on $[a,b]$. Then, for every $n\in \mathbb N$, there exists $x_n\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$. The sequence of points $(x_n)_n$ must have a subsequence converging to a point $x\in [a,b]$,  so $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$. But now, I can not guarantee that $x$ is a point of continuity of $f$, as we only have $f$ continuous a.e.  I want to argue that $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow \infty,$ while it should be converging to $f(x)$, but that does not follow as easily in the classical case.

So, I still wonder, can we say that $f(c)\leq f(x)\leq f(d)$ holds for some $c,d\in [a,b]$ under the hyphotesis that $f$ is continuous a.e.? I couldnt come up with a counter-example with this, altough the mimic of the proof clearly wont work.

Comment: no. it is possible to have $f$ be unbounded if you merely assume continuity a.e. For example, $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ a function which is $0$ everywhere except on the points $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, where you let it take on the value $n$ (or if you want it to be unbounded in both directions, let $f(x_n)=(-1)^nn$).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick counterexample:

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=n$ for $x=1/n$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be defined as $f(x)=x$ for $0\lt x\lt1$ and $f(0)=f(1)=\frac12$.